# Current from HDMI cable

Tags: grounding, cables, hdmi, monitor

I recently purchased a cheap monitor from amazon for using with my laptop. It has a HDMI and VGA output.
I also have a speaker connected to my laptop. when I connect the HDMI cable to my laptop my speaker produces a humming sound.
When I use a tester on HDMI cable it glows and when I touch the HDMI cable with my hand i can feel a tingle not enough to hurt me  but a light tickle.
same with the VGA output.

Will it hurt my  laptop?

Also the laptop is plugged in all the time and the laptop charger, monitor power cord and the speaker power cord is plugged into the same wall outlet using a splitter.

Comment: `Will it hurt my laptop ??` that kind of a question cannot be answered ... only a question like `could it  ....?` is answerable

Comment: Do any of the devices have a three-prong earthed mains plug? Are they connected to a grounded outlet?

Comment: This is frequently caused by a power supply designed for earthed mains connection BUT with no ground supplied (which is what Justme is considering). The 2 x Y capacitors in the power supplies input filtering connect hald mains via the two capacitors to the ground connection. Grounding this as intended by the manufacturer fixes this problem. It CAN destroy SOME equipment.

Answer (score 2):

What youse seeing is probably earth leakage.  I would guess that the monitor isn’t earthed and a small current leaks from the AC supply into the chassis of the monitor, and then out to the cables.  It’s a slight concern that there’s enough that you can feel it, but perhaps you are particularly sensitive to electric current.  Your laptop is almost certainly not earthed (I’m yet to see one that is).  It’s not impossible that you could cause damage by connecting and disconnecting with the monitor plugged in to the AC supply, but generally equipment is designed to be able to withstand this kind of thing.